# ServiceStack.LicenseException with a valid License Key

Tags: servicestack

I am trying to register the license key by the Application_Start method. When I execute Licensing.RegisterLicense("{LicenseKey}"), the method LicenseUtils.ActivatedLicenseFeatures() returns the value "Text". But when I execute new AppHost().Init(), it gives me the following error:

```
Application Exception

ServiceStack.LicenseException

The free-quota limit on '10 ServiceStack Operations' has been reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license or visit https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3 to revert back to the free ServiceStack v3.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): ServiceStack.Text.

Exception stack trace:

  at ServiceStack.LicenseUtils.ApprovedUsage (LicenseFeature licenseFeature, LicenseFeature requestedFeature, Int32 allowedUsage, Int32 actualUsage, System.String message) [0x00026] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.LicenseUtils.AssertValidUsage (LicenseFeature feature, QuotaType quotaType, Int32 count) [0x00118] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceMetadata.Add (System.Type serviceType, System.Type requestType, System.Type responseType) [0x002c9] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.RegisterService (ITypeFactory serviceFactoryFn, System.Type serviceType) [0x00137] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.Register (ITypeFactory serviceFactoryFn) [0x0001a] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.Init () [0x00016] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init () [0x00073] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at API.Global.Application_Start (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00016] in API/Global.asax.cs:163 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch-c6sr1/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295 

Version Information: 4.2.2 (explicit/996df3c Wed Jan 20 00:19:48 EST 2016); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020

Powered by Mono
```

I already tried to update the ServiceStack package, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using a [ServiceStack.Text License](https://servicestack.net/text) which only covers usage for the [ServiceStack.Text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text) NuGet Package with packages from the [full ServiceStack framework](https://servicestack.net/download).